# NA values and Focal Statistics for a Neighborhood of Cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a bathymetry raster, and I am trying to use it to calculate a parameter called the "contour index". This parameter is calculated using the max and min values from a moving window of cells (let's say, 9x9). It's defined as 
"(max depth - min depth)/max depth * 100". Once calculated, the values should range from 0-100.

To try to calculate the contour index, I first used ArcMap-->Spatial Analyst-->Neighbourhood-->Focal Statistics to create a new layer for the min water depth and max water depth in each 9x9 window. I then tried to use the "raster calculator" to calculate the contour index value for each cell.

However, the resulting layer is definitely wrong, with values ranging from -70,000 - 180,000. I honestly am at a loss for what I am doing wrong. Could it be related to NA values in my raster (eg. coastlines and edges of the raster)?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157766/major-bug-in-arcgis-zonal-statistics/158513#158513

Comment: It looks like you made an error in your calculations.  (Those numbers could be close to the max depth multiplied by 100, for instance.) Could you show us specifically what calculations your performed and what the results were at each step?

Answer (score 1):

Focal statistics by default ignore `NoData` thus it shouldn't affect your results

> if a NoData value exists within a neighborhood, the NoData value will be ignore

Maybe you make some mistake in **Raster calculator**.

Try **focal statistics** with **range** option. It gives you raster with max-min within (9x9) window. Then use the same tool with **max** option. Finally use **raster calculator** with expression like `(range/max) * 100`