# How to save numpy array as single band image?

Tags: python, gdal, scipy, opencv

I'm working on MODIS NDVI composite data (single band). I converted the image to a numpy array and performed filtering operations. When i'm saving the new numpy array as an image I get a 3 band image instead of single band image.
How can I save it as a single band image?

```
#read an image
img = cv2.imread("D:/trial/MOD09_NDVI.A2017001.tif")

cv2.namedWindow('Unfiltered Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow('Unfiltered Image',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

#apply filter
myIMG = cv2.blur(img, (5,5))

cv2.namedWindow('Blur Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow('Blur Image', myIMG)

cv2.waitKey(0)

scipy.misc.imsave('D:/trial/blur_55.tif', myIMG)

------------
scipy.misc.imsave('D:/trial/blur_55.tif', myIMG)
```

saves a 3 band image instead of original single band image

Comment: I would recommend rasterio. Check this out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129868/8104

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using for saving Scipy? I think you can use function imwrite from CV2.

For example:

`cv2.imwrite('D:/trial/blur_55.tif', myIMG)`

or you can use also another libraries. For exammple PIL or Matplotlib.

Example for Matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(myIMG)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I was using imwrite as well but I needed to assign spatial references as well. I ended up using GDAL functions for it. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gdal` `driver.Create(filename, xsize, ysize, [bands], [data_type], [options])` function.

For example:

```
from osgeo import gdal

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds = driver.Create('raster.tif', array.shape[0], array.shape[1], 1)
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

out_band.WriteArray(array)
out_ds.FlushCache()

del out_ds, out_band
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar. Thanks for the reply