# Arcpy "MemoryError"; Get Classification Breaks on a TIF Raster; Jenks Breaks; Python

Tags: arcpy, numpy, memoryerror

I have a large .tif raster with integer values. I wish to generate Jenks classification breaks using code and then use those breaks to reclassify my .tif file.

I came across a block of code that I am using to define my Jenks function. Its source is: https://gist.github.com/drewda/1299198

So far I have imported my raster, converted it to a (233,679) 2D array and then converts to a (158207,) 1D array.

Then I attempt to run the function on the array but get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\agates44\Desktop\FinalProject\script1.py", line 80, in <module>
    new = getJenksBreaks(oneDarr,9)
  File "C:\Users\agates44\Desktop\FinalProject\script1.py", line 40, in getJenksBreaks
    mat2.append(temp)
MemoryError
```

My code is below

```
# Define the folder path
folderPath = r'C:\Users\agates44\Desktop\FinalProject' 

# Import modules
import arcpy 
import numpy as np

# Set workspace
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = folderPath
# Allow overwrite
env.overwriteOutput = True

# Get Input Raster properties
inRas = arcpy.Raster('smallorange.tif')
lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(inRas.extent.XMin,inRas.extent.YMin)
cellSize = inRas.meanCellWidth

# Convert Raster to numpy array
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inRas,nodata_to_value=0)
print arr.shape
print arr.dtype
oneDarr = arr.ravel()
print oneDarr.shape
print oneDarr.dtype

def getJenksBreaks(dataList, numClass):
  dataList.sort()
  mat1 = []
  for i in range(0,len(dataList)+1):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0,numClass+1):
      temp.append(0)
    mat1.append(temp)
  mat2 = []
  for i in range(0,len(dataList)+1):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0,numClass+1):
      temp.append(0)
    mat2.append(temp)
  for i in range(1,numClass+1):
    mat1[1][i] = 1
    mat2[1][i] = 0
    for j in range(2,len(dataList)+1):
      mat2[j][i] = float('inf')
  v = 0.0
  for l in range(2,len(dataList)+1):
    s1 = 0.0
    s2 = 0.0
    w = 0.0
    for m in range(1,l+1):
      i3 = l - m + 1
      val = float(dataList[i3-1])
      s2 += val * val
      s1 += val
      w += 1
      v = s2 - (s1 * s1) / w
      i4 = i3 - 1
      if i4 != 0:
        for j in range(2,numClass+1):
          if mat2[l][j] >= (v + mat2[i4][j - 1]):
            mat1[l][j] = i3
            mat2[l][j] = v + mat2[i4][j - 1]
    mat1[l][1] = 1
    mat2[l][1] = v
  k = len(dataList)
  kclass = []
  for i in range(0,numClass+1):
    kclass.append(0)
  kclass[numClass] = float(dataList[len(dataList) - 1])
  countNum = numClass
  while countNum >= 2:#print "rank = " + str(mat1[k][countNum])
    id = int((mat1[k][countNum]) - 2)
    #print "val = " + str(dataList[id])
    kclass[countNum - 1] = dataList[id]
    k = int((mat1[k][countNum] - 1))
    countNum -= 1
  return kclass

new = getJenksBreaks(oneDarr,9)
print new

### used after running getJenksBreaks()
##def classify(value, breaks):
##  for i in range(1, len(breaks)):
##    if value < breaks[i]:
##      return i
##  return len(breaks) - 1
```

How can I figure out which line of my code is using all the memory and what is a workaround I can use?

****** EDIT
The function ran (although it took forever) on the raster size listed above. But that was only a subset of my much larger dataset.

(2400, 2337) 2D array
(5608800,) 1D array

This is when I get the memory error.

Comment: What does task manager say about your memory usage? 233 x 679 isn't a *large* raster, are you sure that your raster is only 233 rows and 679 columns? Be aware that ArcGIS Desktop is only a 32bit application and can only address 2**32 bytes of memory for each instance of Arc - program, script and data.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I apologize, I was wrong. The raster that is generating the memory error is a much larger raster. I was able to generate break values for the smaller subset of the array, which was my original post: [0, 35, 150, 350, 516, 696, 896, 3337, 4132, 428760.0]. Yet I need to run the function on the larger raster, which I fixed in the edit below.

Comment: @MichaelStimson My task manager shows my memory reaching 87% capacity when I run it on the larger raster, and then I get the MemoryError.

Comment: 87% isn't a valuable figure, what is important is the physical load *in mebibytes*, Esri can only address 4 GiB of memory and it sounds like you're filling that up. Considering you're reading the whole raster into memory and performing a purely python function I would suggest you consider either ArcGIS Pro (64 bit) or GDAL 64 bit.. my preference is for GDAL. Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/how-to-fully-load-a-raster-into-a-numpy-array about using GDAL to read a raster into a numpy array.

Comment: How long did the 233, 679 (158207) array take to run?  I roughly guesstimated ~5 hours based on how long it took to run on a 10,000 element array.

Answer (score 1):

A 2400*2337 (assuming single band 32bit) raster is only ~20mb.  I'm not sure why you get a `MemoryError`. I can create a dummy 32bit 2400*2337 ndarray in numpy and run `getJenksBreaks` on it "fine"* in 32bit Python 2.7 from ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

*By "fine", I mean, it will run, but very slowly and I don't see the memory use climb, but I only let it run for a few minutes.

**However...  You *will not* be able to run the pure python Jenks classification on your entire raster.  You will need to sample your raster**

Jenks classification in pure python is *horribly* slow.  You should use a native (i.e. C/C++) jenks library, such as [jenkspy](https://github.com/mthh/jenkspy).

And you need to sample your data, don't try to run it on the entire raster.  You can use `numpy.random.choice(data, size=sample_size, replace=False)` to sample it.  I have tested and found fairly similar class breaks with 25,000 - 100,000 samples (from a 32 bit flow accumulation raster).

Consider the following plots of the time to calculate Jenks breaks against the number of elements. It was generated (in Excel, one day I'll learn how to use matplotlib...) from the results of the code that follows using 100 - 500,000 samples of the dummy data  The solid line shows the pure python Jenks calculation and the dotted line is using `jenkspy`.  Even the `jenkspy` calculation is quite slow once you get over 10,000 values.  I haven't tried running it on the whole 5,608,800,  I'm sure it would take a very, very, very long time...

[image]
[image]

```
import time

import jenkspy
import numpy as np

def getJenksBreaks(dataList, numClass):
    blah blah blah, same code as yours...


nbands, nrows, ncols = 1, 2400, 2337
zmin, zmax = 0, 12345

data = np.random.randint(zmin, zmax, (nbands, nrows, ncols)).astype(np.float32).ravel()

samples = (100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000)
for sample in samples:
    sampled = np.random.choice(data, size=sample, replace=False)

    t=time.time()
    breaks = jenkspy.jenks_breaks(sampled, nb_class=5)
    tj = time.time() - t

    if sample <= 100000:  # Don't bother trying more than 100K
        t=time.time()    # pixels with the pure python version
        breaks = getJenksBreaks(sampled, 5)
        print('%s\t%s\t%s'%(sample, tj, time.time() - t))
    else:
        print('%s\t%s'%(sample, tj)
```

Comment: it is a single band 32bit flow accumulation raster, 21.40mb. Running on ArcMap Desktop 10.5

Comment: @AustinGates Doesn't matter. You will not be able to run the pure python Jenks code  on your entire large raster. Just sample it.