# How to create a TIFF file using GDAL from a numpy array and specifying NoData value

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, nodata

I have some tiff files I obtained from splitting a bigger tiff file using gdal translate. The border tiff files have some nodata values, which I can see in numpy as number 15. I want to manipulate these files as numpy arrays, and then write them back to tiff file. How can I write a numpy array to tiff file, while mantaining the number 15 as the nodata value, so they can be read propertly is GIS programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two functions from the code snippet below, `create_raster` and `numpy_array_to_raster` should do the trick. In terms of maintaining the `NoData` value from the array in the output raster, that is set on the band(s) of a raster with the [`.SetNoDataValue()` method](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a6c7625813411cb5f0500e72d963249c2) which in this code snippet is used in the `numpy_array_to_raster` function. For more information about using `gdal` & `numpy` for raster processing I would highly recommend [Chris Garrard's book Geoprocessing with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/geoprocessing-with-python) and for a quick reference this [gdal/ogr cookbook page](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/) is a great resource.

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
import numpy

# config
GDAL_DATA_TYPE = gdal.GDT_Int32 
GEOTIFF_DRIVER_NAME = r'GTiff'
NO_DATA = 15
SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEM_WKID = 4326

def create_raster(output_path,
                  columns,
                  rows,
                  nband = 1,
                  gdal_data_type = GDAL_DATA_TYPE,
                  driver = GEOTIFF_DRIVER_NAME):
    ''' returns gdal data source raster object

    '''
    # create driver
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(driver)

    output_raster = driver.Create(output_path,
                                  int(columns),
                                  int(rows),
                                  nband,
                                  eType = gdal_data_type)    
    return output_raster

def numpy_array_to_raster(output_path,
                          numpy_array,
                          upper_left_tuple,
                          cell_resolution,
                          nband = 1,
                          no_data = NO_DATA,
                          gdal_data_type = GDAL_DATA_TYPE,
                          spatial_reference_system_wkid = SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEM_WKID,
                          driver = GEOTIFF_DRIVER_NAME):
    ''' returns a gdal raster data source

    keyword arguments:

    output_path -- full path to the raster to be written to disk
    numpy_array -- numpy array containing data to write to raster
    upper_left_tuple -- the upper left point of the numpy array (should be a tuple structured as (x, y))
    cell_resolution -- the cell resolution of the output raster
    nband -- the band to write to in the output raster
    no_data -- value in numpy array that should be treated as no data
    gdal_data_type -- gdal data type of raster (see gdal documentation for list of values)
    spatial_reference_system_wkid -- well known id (wkid) of the spatial reference of the data
    driver -- string value of the gdal driver to use

    '''

    print 'UL: (%s, %s)' % (upper_left_tuple[0],
                            upper_left_tuple[1])

    rows, columns = numpy_array.shape
    print 'ROWS: %s\n COLUMNS: %s\n' % (rows,
                                        columns)

    # create output raster
    output_raster = create_raster(output_path,
                                  int(columns),
                                  int(rows),
                                  nband,
                                  gdal_data_type) 

    geotransform = (upper_left_tuple[0],
                    cell_resolution,
                    upper_left_tuple[1] + cell_resolution,
                    -1 *(cell_resolution),
                    0,
                    0)

    spatial_reference = osr.SpatialReference()
    spatial_reference.ImportFromEPSG(spatial_reference_system_wkid)
    output_raster.SetProjection(spatial_reference.ExportToWkt())
    output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    output_band = output_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    output_band.SetNoDataValue(no_data)
    output_band.WriteArray(numpy_array)          
    output_band.FlushCache()
    output_band.ComputeStatistics(False)

    if os.path.exists(output_path) == False:
        raise Exception('Failed to create raster: %s' % output_path)

    return  output_raster
```

Comment: for some reason I don't have the method SetNoDataValue. Why could that?

Comment: @Symbionte make sure that you are working with the `band` object not the `raster data source` object. You get the `band` object by calling `.GetRasterBand(1)` (it is a 1 based index not 0) on the `raster data source` object. Then you shou ld be able to use the `.SetNoDataValue()` method on the `band`. See [here](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html) and [here](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a6c7625813411cb5f0500e72d963249c2) for more info.

Comment: I did, it doesn't show either in the band object, nor the output dataset object.

Comment: My mistake, it works on the band object. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4):

To read (from: [How to fully load a raster into a numpy array?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/how-to-fully-load-a-raster-into-a-numpy-array?rq=1)):

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open("mypic.tif")
cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
```

To write:

```
# create the output image
driver = ds.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create("outimage.tif", cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)
outBand.SetNoDataValue(15)
outBand.WriteArray(myarray)
outDs.SetGeoTransform(trans)
```

Comment: for some reason I don't have the method SetNoDataValue. Why could that?

Comment: A `GDALDataset` object (outDs in your code) does not have the method `.SetNoDataValue()` as you use in your code snippet. [See here for more info](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html).