# layer stack TIFF using python

Tags: python, modis

i work with EVI MODIS and i need to stack all raster i had using python but i don't know how

i'm using this backag and script to read my rasters

```
    import os
    import glob
    from osgeo import gdal
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.ndimage
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt
    import rasterio as rio


    #repertoire de travail 

    inDir = r'D:\MODIS\Doy2000/'
    os.chdir(inDir)  
    #repertoir sorti 

    outDir = os.path.normpath(os.path.split(inDir)[0] + os.sep + 'output') + '\\' 
    if not os.path.exists(outDir): os.makedirs(outDir)

    # Create list of MODIS rasters for surface reflectance
    modis_EVI = glob.glob('MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_**.tif')

modis_EVI
Out[32]: 
['MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000225_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000241_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000257_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000273_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000289_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000305_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000321_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000337_aid0001.tif',
 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000353_aid0001.tif']
```

but idon't know how stack all my raster in python 
need help i'm very new in python

Comment: Use gdal_merge. There are many suggestion how to do it in documentation of this function.

Comment: start here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/how-to-fully-load-a-raster-into-a-numpy-array and also look at `numpy.dstack`

Comment: @MarcPfister i need to transform all my rasters to array with numpy that first step ? sorry my english

Comment: @DiogoCaribé i need documentation

Comment: See here https://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge the input you need to use regular expression in order to add all bands

Comment: @DiogoCaribé thanks but i have question i have bigtiff whene i do ` raster = rasterio.open(MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif')` i had error that is problem rasterio is not defined ?